Filter associated entity on one query with hibernate and jpa?
I have question how to filter associated entity for example I have entity A
public class A {
 private Long id;
 @OneToMany
 private List<B> bList;
}

and entity B:
public class B {
 private Long id;
 private Boolean isActive;
 @ManyToOne
 private A a;
}

And for example I want to get List of A entities with filtered fetched B entities with isActive = true. But the problem is, that I want to do it in one query without foreach loop and searching separately B entities. I heared about @FilterJoinTable but this invoke another query to search B entity even if B entity is fetched eagerly. Also I try criteria api with listJoin an use .on() function but this doesn't work. So maybe there is no solution to get A entity with filtered B entity in one query and I should use only stream filter?

from A join fetch bList b where b.isActive: translete this query to criteria is not so difficult (is just a join-fetch with a clause)

You can add @SQLRestriction("isActive=true") to List<B> bList.
Note that you can't turn it off.
